# Ayuda con MVC (pasar datos de html a un controlador)

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Buenas noches a todos necesito ayuda con algo tengo en una vista algo como esto

```html
<h5>Cuanto es 16/8</h5>
            <div class="radio-btns">
                <div class="swit">
                    <div class="check_box_one"> <div class="radio1"> <label><input type="radio" name="radio1" checked=""><i></i>2</label> </div></div>
                    <div class="check_box"> <div class="radio1"> <label><input type="radio" name="radio1"><i></i>4</label> </div></div>
                    <div class="check_box"> <div class="radio1"> <label><input type="radio" name="radio1"><i></i>3</label> </div></div>
                    <div class="check_box"> <div class="radio1"> <label><input type="radio" name="radio1"><i></i>8</label> </div></div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Lo cual es una pregunta(enrealidad son 5 en total) con 4 opciones de selección multiple y lo que necesito es como pasar la selección del usuario al controlador para hacer la debida lógica para saber cuanto saca de nota final muchas gracias y espero ayuda

Answer (score 2):

Lo más fácil es asignarle la propiedad "name" al radio, dentro de un form.

Y eso lo recibe el controller como un un parámetro.

Tu vista quedaría algo así:

```
<form method="post">
    <h5>Cuanto es 16/8</h5>
    <div class="radio-btns">
        <fieldset class="swit" name="answer1" >
            <div class="check_box_one">
                <div class="radio1"> <label><input type="radio" name="radio1" value="2" checked=""><i></i>2</label> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="check_box">
                <div class="radio1"> <label><input type="radio" name="radio1" value="4"><i></i>4</label> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="check_box">
                <div class="radio1"> <label><input type="radio" name="radio1"  value="3"><i></i>3</label> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="check_box">
                <div class="radio1"> <label><input type="radio" name="radio1"  value="8"><i></i>8</label> </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <p style="color:red">
        @ViewBag.Respuesta
    </p>
    <button type="submit">Marcar</button>
</form>
```

Luego tu controlador:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(){
       return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(int radio1)
    {
        // toda tu logica aqui
        ViewBag.Respuesta = radio1;
        return View();
    }
```

Espero te ayude.